# "Compact" formula for counting all products of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$(in that order)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, magma

So here is the problem (I.1.3 in Grillet's Abstract Algebra)

Let $X$ be a set with a binary operation $\cdot:X \times X \to X,$ where $\cdot(x,y):= xy, \text{ for all } x,y\in X$.

A **product** $x\in X $ of $\,x_1, \ldots, x_n \in X$ (in that order) is defined in the following way.

**(1)** If $n=1,$ then the only possibility is $x=x_1.$

**(2)** If $n\geq 2,$ then $x$ is a product of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$(in that order) iff for some $1\leq k < n$, $\, x=yz,$ where $y$ is a product of $x_1, \ldots, x_k$(in that order) and $z$ is a product of $x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n$ (in that order).

> Count all possible products of $x_1,\ldots, x_n$(in that order) for $n=6,7,8.$

For example $x=x_1(x_2x_3)\lor x=(x_1x_2)x_3$ are all the possible products for $n=3.$

I constructed all the products for $n=4$ and $n=5$ (previous exercises) and came up with an answer.

Let $|\Pi_n|$ denote the number all possible products of $x_1,\ldots, x_n$(in that order). Then

$$\big\vert \,\Pi_n  \big\vert= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\big\vert \,\Pi_k  \big\vert \cdot\big\vert \,\Pi_{n-k}  \big\vert \,\,\,(n\geq 2)$$

I haven't proved it, but by going through the motions with $n=4$ and $n=5,$ I feel very comfortable with it. So I got
$$\big\vert \,\Pi_6  \big\vert =42, \big\vert \,\Pi_7  \big\vert =132, \big\vert \,\Pi_8  \big\vert=429 $$

The problem with it is that in order to count, for example, $\big\vert \,\Pi_{100}  \big\vert$ you need to know the result for all $n\leq 99.$

> **Is there a formula for doing the calculation without needing all the previous ones?**

Thanks for your help in advance. If my formula is not correct, please say so.

Comment: Feels like complete induction to me, for sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks! Never knew those numbers existed.

Comment: No problem. For future reference, if you ever encounter an integer sequence which you're trying to learn more about, the OEIS (https://oeis.org) is extremely useful.